# sudo xcode select switch command not working

Tags: xcode, terminator

sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app command not working, I have a OS Sierra and Xcode 8 installed. I either get no reply and command moves to next line or i get an error. Please Help i want to change directory

Comment: (To make literal text stand out, you can put it between "backticks" `\`\``.) `xcode-select` looks funny - shouldn't the be a blank space before the dash?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `xcode-select` as root. Therefore, simply execute the following command in Terminal:

`sudo xcode-select -s "/Applications/Xcode.app"`

Comment: True that. My bad.

Comment: Ive tried that too, it still just goes to the next line without performing any function.

Comment: Im learning an online course on objective c and the same function the instructor performs on his mac does not work on my mac, please help with other suggestions if possible

Comment: Well, just a thought: If you just want to switch the Xcode command line toolchain you can also do that in Xcode directly. Go to `Xcode` -> `Preferences` -> `Locations` and select your toolchain via `Command Line Tools`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your setting for DEVELOPER_DIR environment variable. You may be over-riding it. Find out with:

> echo $DEVELOPER_DIR

In your ~/.bash_profile add:

> export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app

Found the answer in https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13629